# How to create a search bar with mic icon in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uisearchbar, ios13

In iOS 13, search bars in all Apple apps have a mic icon on the right that allows for voice input. However, when I create a system search bar (or UISearchController), I don't get the mic icon. I've searched on Google and SO and couldn't find the answer - is it something we can adopt, and if so how?

Answer (score 5):

One important note is that currently there is not a way to programmatically put the user into "Dictation mode". This means to implement this, your must use the `Speech` framework in order to get "speech-to-text" working from a button press.

You can accomplish the visual styling by updating the image for the search bar's bookmark icon and setting `showsBookmarkButton` on the search bar to true.

Here is an implementation with a `UISearchController`:

```swift
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
let micImage = UIImage(systemName: "mic.fill")
searchController.searchBar.setImage(micImage, for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
```

You handle the button tap via the search bar's delegate:

```swift
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

```swift
func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Do work here
}
```